# BL:GotY PS4 Online Timeouts

Tags: ps4, borderlands

I am currently having an issue where any online match I try to join in Borderlands Game of the Year times out. It's been a while since I played the series but it happens for every game i have tried to join with no success yet. I am trying to Google and YouTube and only found one relevant piece of info:

I thought maybe it was my own personal issue but I was curious if anyone knows of this. I tried finding a way to contact Gearbox to no avail. Any other online service I am using on LAN is working fine. My Upload/Download looks good on Speedtest with only a 40ms ping. Thoughts on what might be occurring or any relevant info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gearbox's forum is flooded with connectivity issues. I was able to find two remedies that you could try.

- Create a game, set it to offline and then set it to public or toggle the privacy settings for private games.
- [Port-forwarding/opening](https://www.psu.com/news/borderlands-goty-connection-issues-port-forwarding/). Many players were able to connect successfully by opening/forwarding the following two ports to their PS4:

  - 2900
  - 7777

You can also read through [this thread](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/ps4-bl-goty-connection-issue/2058469) on Gearbox's forums.

Comment: Thank you. I felt stupid not being able to fund their forums anywhere or any kind if support. All I found was there ZenDesk.